# Making a DB9 Cable

Tags: serial, rs232, db9

I need to make a DB9 cable due to the need to have a custom pin out. I will get a few [StarTech.com DB9 Serial Male D-Sub Crimp Connector (C9PCM)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00066HQPA) to get started.

1. What crimping tool do I need to secure my wires to the DB9 connector pins? Or is this done by soldering? I have only crimped molex connectors.
2. What do I need to get to hold/sleeve together all the individual cables together?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative I recommend screw-type connectors.

[image] [image]

They are easy to wire for one-off jobs, can be rewired if you make a mistake and easy to inspect. Note that they are more bulky than soldered connectors.

Search for DB9 9Pin D-Sub Connector solderless Terminal Board Plastic Cover.

> Am I looking for a shielded cable with 9 wires in it, so I can connect them to the DB9 connector? What search terms should I use if I want to find them on Amazon/eBay?

You need as many cores as the device requires. Some just need TX (transmit) and RX (receive) and ground. Others use some handshaking signals. You need to read the documentation for the devices you are connecting.

Search for shielded data cable.

> Or is it common practice to get an existing DB9 cable and cut off both ends to wire our own DB9 connectors to them?

You wouldn't be the first to do that. If you have one to spare you could cut one end off and free-wire the other using the suggested connectors. It would cut your work in half. Test for end to end continuity to see how many cores it has connected through (to check that it's enough) before you cut.

Comment: Sounds like what I need for a start! What can we use to sleeve/cover all the individual cables connecting the 2 connectors? I searched Amazon for db9 jacket but cant find it.

Comment: You use a multicore, shielded cable as you would for any serial or data cable.

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new here. Am I looking for a shielded cable with 9 wires in it, so I can connect them to the DB9 connector? What search terms should I use if I want to find them on Amazon/eBay?

Comment: Or is it common practice to get an existing DB9 cable and cut off both ends to wire our own DB9 connectors to them?

Comment: Comments answered in question update.

Comment: Kids today!!  There is only ONE way to deal with DB9 cables.  Go to your trusty drawer of unlabeled DB25-DB9 adapters, null modems, and gender changers.  Stack them up in random configs until the cable does what you need it to do.  Then, tie up the resulting stack of unlabeled adaptors/gender changers/null modems so it can never come apart, then slowly refill the random drawer over time so you can do it again the next time you need to.

Comment: @Scott: Us old timers have all done that. I wonder how many man-hours were wasted sorting out RS232 problems because they didn't have a standard connector and pinout. I was delighted when I found the LED testers and these rewireable devices. Note that OP hasn't specified RS232!

Comment: I noticed that it wasn't RS232 -- but  25 to 9's and null modems are all powerful.

Comment: This is for RS232 :)

Answer (score 1):

Both solder and crimp pins are avail at same price. Solder is better, Crimp is faster for mass production using a "two-stage" crimp on both insulation and conductor.  Avail from any distributor with recommend tools.

Cheap crimp tools need pressure skill, expensive ones don't need as much skill.

Unless you want to master this method and pass the 5 pund pull test on each crimp, just go with soldering.

Strain relief clamps on shell should bind the insulation. Otherwise use a plastic cable tie.

Comment: [Is this the solder pin version](https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Assembled-Connector-Backshell-C9PSF/dp/B00066HQ7S) that you are referring to?

Comment: yes it says soldered